# Laravel Class 'Socialite' not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-socialite

Using composer, I have installed Socialite package to my local machine. It works well. Then I upload all the `vendor/laravel/socialite` directory as it is to server. Then on server, in `composer.json` added the line -

```
"laravel/socialite": "^2.0"
```

Also, in  config/app.php make below changes -

In provider section add the line -

```
Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider::class,
```

In aliases section add this line -

```
'Socialite' => Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::class,
```

Then, as per [documentation](https://blog.damirmiladinov.com/laravel/laravel-5.2-socialite-facebook-login.html#.V-N-hCali1G) add below code in config/services.php file -

```
'facebook' => [
    'client_id' => '{{my_client_id}}',
    'client_secret' => '{{my_secret_key}}',
    'redirect' => 'http://mydomain/public/callback',
    ],
```

The Controller, I am using has included `use Socialite;` at top.

Bur now, it gives me error as `Class 'Socialite' not found` on server. Where as it works fine on my local machine.
Am I missing something to upload on server?

Your help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Update composer on server site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do dump autoload everytime you make changes in composer.json, `composer dump-auto`